# How to reverse a unicode string?

Tags: css

We have an arrow from right side '➜' but couldn't get reverse of it. 
Here is the CSS part which I had tried but it does not work.

```
.button span{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
 }
```

Comment: Add your html code

Comment: @xmaster why would the HTML matter in this case ? it's clearly a span which is a child of an element with class `button`  . For eg `<a  class="button">Click<span> ➜</span></a>` .

Comment: @MihaiT It matters because OP may not be using the correct selector, the html could be malformed etc etc. Without the HTML we have no way of knowing.

Comment: @Turnip Wanted to say that regardless of the HTML structure used it's clearly that he wants to use transform on a span and transform doesn't work on inline elements ( span ) . So it's easy to know what the problem is just by looking at the CSS code provided by the OP without any other information.